# Inserting entries in a list without sorting the output

Tags: python

I have two lists as follows:

`l1 = [1,3,5,7]` and `l2 = [2,4,6]`

how can I get this output `l3 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` ,that is, inserting the first entry from l2 as second entry in l1 and so on. Thanks in advance

Comment: Use can use a modified version of iterations of insertion sort.

Comment: Since the lists are already sorted, you simply merge the lists.  If you want to insert, use the list `insert` method.  Where are you stuck?

Comment: I think this is more "Unclear" than a dup. OP should confirm (a) whether input lists are always sorted; (b) whether output result is required to be sorted.

Comment: @greatunarine1, will you be able to advise on the 2 questions above?

Answer (score 0):

Without assuming the input lists are sorted, or requiring the output be sorted, you can use `itertools` for this.

```
from itertools import zip_longest, chain

l1 = [1,3,5,7]
l2 = [2,4,6]

res = list(filter(None, chain.from_iterable(zip_longest(l1, l2))))

# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

**Explanation**

- Use `zip_longest` to iterate lists of unequal length pairwise.
- Use `chain.from_iterable` to efficiently chain the list of lists.
- Use `filter(None, ...)` to remove the final `None` element.

Comment: `chain.from_iterable([i, j] for i, j in zip_longest(l1, l2))` is a slow way to write `chain.from_iterable(zip_longest(l1, l2))`; no need for the effectively no-op genexpr. This does assume the OP wants intercalation, not combining of arbitrary sorted inputs (that is, they *don't* want `l1 = [1, 2, 3]; l2 = [4, 5, 6]` to produce `l3 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`, but instead would want `l3 = [1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6]`).

Comment: All answers provided above works very well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way that relies on the input lists being sorted in advance in an alternating order like your example, such that you actually want to *intercalate* them, rather than doing any type of sorted merge.

And that the value `None` would never serve as a true value among your lists.

```
In [12]: from itertools import chain, ifilter, izip_longest 

In [13]: list(ifilter(lambda x: x is not None, chain(*izip_longest(l1, l2))))
Out[13]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: Assuming intercalation is what the OP wants this is fine, but I'd suggest replacing `chain(*izip_longest(l1, l2))` with `chain.from_iterable(izip_longest(l1, l2))` to avoid forcing the `izip_longest` iterator to be fully realized (holding a bunch of `tuple`s in memory) when it can be lazily consumed with lower overhead (no more than one such `tuple` in memory at once). You could also create a guaranteed unique sentinel value (`sentinel = object()`) and use it as the `izip_longest` `fillvalue` and `ifilter` test element (`x is not sentinel`) to remove the assumption that `None` doesn't appear.

Comment: I'll agree the optimization is largely meaningless unless the inputs are huge (millions of values sort of thing). That said, using a guaranteed unique sentinel is about reliability/correctness in all cases, not performance. Sure, if this is for a one-off solution where the inputs are guaranteed to only be `int`s, go nuts, use `None`, but if you plan to reuse the code in any way, don't make assumptions that are invalidated by perfectly reasonable inputs.